# How to resolve Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR"?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to upload a basic Dialog script into Netsuite and received this error: Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"syntax error (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#22)","stack":[]}

Here is the script, I'm not sure what's wrong with it. I added the entry point  pageInit(scriptContext) because originally I received this error: "SuiteScript 2.x entry point scripts must implement one script type function."

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */




define(['N/ui/dialog'],
    function(dialog) {function pageInit(scriptContext) {
        var options = {
            title: 'Critical Items',
            message: 'Click OK to continue.'
         };
        function success(result) {
            console.log('Success with value ' + result);
        }
        function failure(reason) {
            console.log('Failure: ' + reason);
        }

        dialog.alert(options).then(success).catch(failure);
        return{
            pageInit:pageInit
        }`enter code here`
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to remember -

1. Check for paranthesis. The one you open needs to be closed.
2. Your return statement should be outside of the functions.

Here you go -

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */




define(['N/ui/dialog'],function(dialog) {

    function pageInit(scriptContext) {
       var options = {
           title: 'Critical Items',
           message: 'Click OK to continue.'
        };
       function success(result) {
           console.log('Success with value ' + result);
       }
       function failure(reason) {
           console.log('Failure: ' + reason);
       }
       dialog.alert(options).then(success).catch(failure);
       
    }

    return{
        pageInit:pageInit
    }
});
```

Let me know in case of any issues in comments below